# Angular 6 Redirect to startup component of an application if a user changed his password using navigateByUrl is not working

Tags: angular, angular6, router

I am currently at the following url of my angular 6 app:

```
http://localhost:4200/dashboard/admin/users
```

If an admin changed his credentials, i need to redirect him to login component again.

```
this.auth.updateCredentials(credentials).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    if (data == "success") {
      this.showError = false;
      if (credentials['user_id'] == this.loggedUser) {
        //Redirect
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', '')
        localStorage.setItem('user_id', '')
        localStorage.setItem('user_role', '')
        this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
      } else {
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    }
    if (data == "error") {
      this.showError = true;
    }

  },
  (error) => {
    this.showError = true;
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

I tried `this.router.navigateByUrl('login');`, `this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');`

but no errors and no redirections

Comment: this.router.navigate(['/your-path']);

Comment: Try `this.router.navigate(['/login'])`

Comment: can i see ur route file?

Comment: It didn't work guys @IgorLitvinovich

Comment: Where do you call this code? Is it inside a component or another service?

Comment: `this.router.navigateByUrl('login')` is your code being executed ?

Comment: Did you import the Router from  '@angular/router'? sometimes visual code imports it from different places and it causes errors

Comment: Yes I imported the router module

Comment: See my ans and tell me its work or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import import {Router} from '@angular/router';
and in constructor private router: Router

If you are passing your service request as a json than your code is like

```
this.auth.updateCredentials(credentials).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    if (data) {
      this.showError = false;
      if (credentials['user_id'] == this.loggedUser) {
        //Redirect
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', '')
        localStorage.setItem('user_id', '')
        localStorage.setItem('user_role', '')
         this.router.navigate(['your link']).then(() => {
                  your toaster
                });
      } else {
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    }
    if (data == "error") {
      this.showError = true;
    }

  },
  (error) => {
    this.showError = true;
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

And if you are not parsing your data to json in advance then you have to do this

```
this.auth.updateCredentials(credentials).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    if (data['status'] == 200) {
      this.showError = false;
      if (credentials['user_id'] == this.loggedUser) {
        //Redirect
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', '')
        localStorage.setItem('user_id', '')
        localStorage.setItem('user_role', '')
        this.router.navigate(['your link']).then(() => {
                    your toaster
      } else {
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    }
    if (data == "error") {
      this.showError = true;
    }

  },
  (error) => {
    this.showError = true;
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
constructor(..., private router: Router, ...) {}
...
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
...
```

Comment: it didn't worked at all, it just stayed at current component

Comment: @alim1990, any errors on the console? Try placing a breakpoint on that line to check if the control actually break on that breakpoint.

Comment: Nope. that what making crazy

Answer (score 1):

if you're using

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
```

make sure you have it in your contructor as

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {}
```

and use the forward slash to specify a route

```
 this._router.navigateByUrl("/login")
```

perhaps that is what you where missing. I hope it helps.